# How to save pandas dataframe into file fixed size of records?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have created one dataframe which has 1000 records. But I need to save only 100 records in a file. It should be starting from 100. Could you please suggest me any solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# Creating a dataframe with 1000 rows
df=pd.DataFrame()
df=df.append(["x"]*1000)


# Loop
i=0

while i <len(df)-1:
   df.iloc[i:i+100,:].to_excel("output_{0}_{1}.xlsx".format(i,i+100),index=False)
   i+=100
```

This method will give you 10 excel files with 100 records each

Answer (score 0):

```
df.iloc[100:200, :].to_csv('filename.csv')
```